# Should all questions be tagged with the system(s) they are valid on?

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should questions always be tagged with either a console/platform or with “multi-platform”?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50/should-questions-always-be-tagged-with-either-a-console-platform-or-with-multi-p)

And what about multi-system games where the question does not specify whether the system is relevant for an answer?

Comment: @Oak right you are... Shall I wait for the question to be closed or just delete this post?

Comment: close :)