# Mandatory tags for platform?

Tags: discussion, tags

> We appear to have instant consensus that a game tag (or game series tag) should be applied to all questions on specific titles.
>
> <sub>[link](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50/should-questions-always-be-tagged-with-either-a-console-platform-or-with-multi-p/55#55)</sub>
>
> ---
>
> The only added value I see in adding it is for filtering purposes - and while that is admittedly useful, I think it will encumber the tagging system a bit too much.
>
> <sub>[link](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50/should-questions-always-be-tagged-with-either-a-console-platform-or-with-multi-p/55#55)</sub>

Meta has a set of mandatory tags (`discussion`, `support`, `bug`, ...). If you feel console tags would be so advantageous to the site, we could have mandatory tags for the main site itself.

However, chances are there would be too many to enumerate. `pc`, `console`, `console-agnostic`; `xbox`, `xbox-360`, `wii`, `ps`, `ps2`, `ps3`, `gba`, `gameboy-color`, `gameboy-classic`, ...

Comment: Here, have a [list of X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_video_game_consoles)

Comment: don't forget arcade :(

Comment: Is there a purpose that the question-to-be received so many downvotes, apart from that it doesn't look like a question? Are we voting on something else by voting it up/down?

Comment: @Bora People disagree with the proposal in the question. I'd downvote it myself if I could now

Answer (score 15):

I don't think there's any small set of categories every question will fall under. What if I want to play games on my phone? Or on a calculator? (Yes, I do play Doom on mine).

In short, no, I don't think this'll work. We can always add tags later, retagging doesn't require a lot of rep.

Comment: Well, the real problem would be maintaining the list and handling the error message which, if it worked like it currently does, would be overlong.

Comment: That, and it would simply drive people away from the site. You go from a community-run site to a moderated site where only specific questions can be asked. We're already close-happy, I don't think we should be aggravating the problem further.

Comment: ..or on a software device simulator? (vmware,dosbox,Cider,WINE)