# Dwarf fortress platform tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Recently I noticed many of the questions in the `[dwarf-fortress]` tag had been re-tagged to add `[pc]`.  ([List](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dwarf-fortress+pc))

This doesn't cause a problem, but it seems a little silly, especially since the [current release of DF](http://www.bay12games.com/dwarves/) is multi-platform (windows, mac, and linux).

Shouldn't we just leave questions alone that don't really involve a particular platform, or should we aim for tagging everything possible.

---

> Related: [Mandatory Platform Tag](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/552/mandatory-tags-for-platform)

Comment: Sorry about that, that's my fault. I absent-mindedly forgot that PC means a computer running Windows, since I tend to associate the term with a computer running any OS for some reason. Also, I was retagging because I agree with http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50/should-questions-always-be-tagged-with-either-a-console-platform-or-with-multi-p 's second answer.

Comment: @Mana You probably associate that because "PC" can stand for "personal computer" in the sense of "the computer that I own". We may eventually need a better tag for "computer games".

Comment: @Grace I've though of PC being Personal Computer since the 90s (when I used Mac OS 7).

Comment: @Grace @tzenes I like that definition better, but unfortunately MS has cornered that term.

Comment: @tzenes ping ♪ because only one comment reply works at a time

Comment: Really @Grace? Didn't know that... so many multiple notification I tried to send in the past and now I know they didn't reach the recipient... *sigh*... poor little things

Comment: I don't think MS cornered the term as much as Apple distanced themselves from it (and the PowerPC).  Also, love the note @Grace

Comment: also related: [Should questions always be tagged with either a console/platform or with “multi-platform”?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50/should-questions-always-be-tagged-with-either-a-console-platform-or-with-multi-p)

Answer (score 6):

> Shouldn't we just leave questions alone that don't really involve a particular platform, or should we aim for tagging everything possible.

My opinion is: Leave questions alone that don't really involve a particular platform (it would be *wrong* to tag them with one if it applies also to others)

Comment: So what do you suggest when we stumble upon questions tagged with a platform although it's irrelevant? Removing or leaving as is? I still somehow hope the [implicit tagging idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58073/tagging-hierarchy) will be accepted to help both points of view in [that tagging question](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50/should-questions-always-be-tagged-with-either-a-console-platform-or-with-multi-p)

Answer (score 2):

Wait a second, you mean a PC running Linux or Mac is not a PC? The tag isn't `[windows]`. I don't see the problem.

The correct tag is `[pc]` because that's the platform. It's `[pc]` as in "not a `[ps3]`", not `[pc]` as in "not a `[mac]`".

Comment: badp, I agree it should be that way, but it's not the way people use it.  When people say a "I got this great game for PC" they mean Windows, they'll say Mac or Linux when they mean that.  Should we have a `[Windows]` tag for the 95% of *personal computer* games that are Windows only?

Comment: No, we should have a `[pc]` tag for the 100% of _personal computer_ games. :)