# Console tags, any consensus yet?

Tags: discussion, tags, gaming-hardware

Yesterday, [Someone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/1057/jason-berkan) removed the [**Wii**] tag from  <strike>almost all</strike> many Wii questions.

I rolled-back is modification [on the question I asked](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5099/fastest-way-to-get-1-ups) because I found those tag really useful; In my interesting tags, there's [**Wii**] and [**DS**] and I put [**PS3**], [**XBox**] and [**XBox-360**] in my ignored tags.

Is there any community consensus about those tags? Is that a good thing that he removed that tag or we should re-tag those questions back?

**Update:**

[Someone else](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/23/badp) just put those tags back. Is that a good thing either? 
(I was expecting this, so that why I asked this question so we could discuss it before a Re-tagging war start.)

Comment: The actions of Jason were actually consistent with [Oak's proposal here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50/should-questions-always-be-tagged-with-either-a-console-platform-or-with-multi-p). There's technically been no actual consensus on that, nor [on the genre tag](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/836/when-should-we-use-genre-tags).

Comment: "almost all"? - I removed it on all of them that were not specifically about the Wii console.  :)
I did it based on Oak's proposal as Grace Note noted (heh), and also based on the fact that I did not see any platform specific tags in any of the recent questions, only on older questions.  My assumption was that there had been a consensus that the extra tags were not required.
(Plus, I was compiling...)
If there hasn't been any consensus, then I shall leave the tags alone.

Comment: @Jason Berkan So, if those platform Tags are useful and not Harmful, I don't get the goal of this action. Is there any "value" added by it? (I think "NO") Is there any "value" removed by it? (I think "YES") While I don't think those tags should be obligatory, I think they definitively add some useful information to the question.

Comment: Sorry, I left out the point where my personal view matched the answer - I don't see any value in having Super Mario Galaxy 2 tagged with Wii, since that is the only platform you can play it on.  And while I have a Wii, I don't have (or care) about all the games on that platform, so I would never add Wii to my interesting tags.  Since my view matched what I thought the consensus was, I figured I would clean up some older questions.

Comment: I agree with you that adding the Tag of the consoles I got to my interesting tag is don't give a big productivity gain, but adding the Tag of the console I don't have to the ignored tag did help me a lot. That why I support this idea.

Comment: @DavRob60 for a cross platform game, though, doesn't the ignore tag hurt you? If a game on a console you like is also on a console you ignore now you'll never see that game...

Comment: @tzenes Yes, but that why I added a The console I own in my interested tags. Also, I did not check the "Hide Ignored Tags", That way, those games are both blurred AND highlighted. Note that I don't think that There should be and obligatory console for every question, I think they are specifically useful for game that are console exclusive. If they are tagged as [multi-platform] there is no hiding problems, but I think those game shouldn't have a console Tag anyway.

Comment: Regarding your edit, I don't think there will be a retagging war (at least, I won't participate). It looks like the current consensus is to leave it alone - if people tag with the console it is OK, but if they don't, that is also OK. I can live with that.

Comment: @Jason Berkan I agree, but it's a good thing to clarify this, since your where assuming that "there had been a consensus that the extra tags were not required."

Answer (score 11):

According to [this question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50/should-questions-always-be-tagged-with-either-a-console-platform-or-with-multi-p) and [this question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/552/mandatory-tags-for-platform), platform tags should not be mandatory. Whether the tag should be **allowed** or not is a different matter; personally I think that using these tags in that manner should be allowed, because

1. There's no harm in these tags
2. They might be useful for some users (see [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50/should-questions-always-be-tagged-with-either-a-console-platform-or-with-multi-p/171#171))
3. Many new questions are bound to appear with their platforms as an additional tag, and enforcing that platform tags will only appear in a small subset of these questions will require a lot of maintenance.

So while I don't think that user did anything wrong, I do not support retagging questions to remove platform tags when it is not deemed as necessary.

I am a bit hesitant about this, though, because it can lead to tagging inconsistency; is it okay for some questions will be platform-tagged and some not? I don't like it but I can live with it.

Comment: If you consider badges though, tacking on console tags would gain you extra badges for each console. If i tag XBOX360GAME with [xbox360game] and [xbox360] then it makes me get the [xbox360] badge that much faster.

Comment: @Noctrine How does this differ from a scenario where someone were to get a tag badge on Stack Overflow for [c#] and all they ever looked at was [c#3.0]?

Comment: "I don't like it but I can live with it."  Excellent quote.

Comment: @Noctrine If people are so concerned with tag badges that they want to tag everything [xbox360] then I'd say they've missed the point of this site.  Badges are a nice reward for doing good things, but if someone is trying to "game" the system, then why bother? Not that I'm accusing you of this behavior.

Comment: @tzenes & @gracenote, I was just thinking of a potential harmful case. My personal view is like Oak's, I don't like it because it can lead to inconsistency but it really doesn't matter to me.

Comment: @Noctrine I wasn't trying to accuse you of anything, I'm merely suggesting its symptomatic of a larger problem.  This is not a hill I'm willing to die on either.

Answer (score 2):

The way I see this, is that console tags are actually mandatory, but due to technical difficulties, and the problems with maintaining an exhaustive list, not enforced using technical measures.

A comparison can be made with the coding language tags for coding questions on Stack Overflow; while not enforced in code, it is basically mandatory to add a tag describing the language used.

### Pro

- Allows for filtering/following/ignoring questions based on console.
- Better for SEO.

### Cons

- <s>No way to differentiate questions about the console itself</s> (this can be done by adding the `[hardware]` tag to the question, in addition to the console)

Comment: I actually struggle with the comparison to SO language tags.  Those are required because it is often impossible to answer the question without knowing what language / framework the problem is in.  For games, the game's tag gives you enough information to know what platform is being referred (with the exception of multi-platform games).

Comment: I don't think it is that hard to answer an untagged coding question, it just requires a lot more work; Also it allows people not familiar with a certain game, but familiar with the console it runs on in general, to answer the question anyways (with some google-fu); without the console tag, they never even looked at the question.

Comment: somethings might also be diffrent between fallout nv on xbox360 vs PC, since the xbox version doesn't allow using the console for excample.