# What is the right way to tag a game that has multiple platforms?

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should questions always be tagged with either a console/platform or with “multi-platform”?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50/should-questions-always-be-tagged-with-either-a-console-platform-or-with-multi)
>   [Platform Tags are Useless](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4638/platform-tags-are-useless)

I was reading a question about Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning where it became obvious that the OP was talking about the PC version. In this case, I couldn't answer as I play on the PS3 and the question doesn't apply.

When we have games that span multiple platforms, and the question is about a specific platform, should we tag the platform as well as the game to make it clearer what the question is about?

Comment: Also see: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3401/should-i-tag-a-request-by-the-associated-console

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> There has been some changes in policy. Please see LessPops Meta: [Platform Tags are Useless](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4638/platform-tags-are-useless)

<s>If the question and answers will only apply to certain versions of the game based on the platform, it should be tagged with those platforms.</s>

Comment: This is correct.