# Do some of these Steam tagged questions deserve the tag?

Tags: discussion

Do some of these Steam tagged questions deserve the tag? Maybe the last one does.

[What are the chances behind what items you get in chests/boxes in Counter Strike: GO?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/152479/what-are-the-chances-behind-what-items-you-get-in-chests-boxes-in-counter-strike)
This is about CS:GO gameplay mechanic. Tagged with it as well.

[The game won't detect my Xbox 360 controller anymore](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/154702/the-game-wont-detect-my-xbox-360-controller-anymore)
This is a tech support question on why their controller stopped working. Rebooting fixed it. Its also tagged with SSF4.

[What steps am I missing to make TF2 render a demo as h264?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/155249/what-steps-am-i-missing-to-make-tf2-render-a-demo-as-h264)
TF2 question about rendering demos as H264. Also tagged with TF2 and H264.

[Press any key to continue: no response](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/156767/press-any-key-to-continue-no-response)
Okayish, not a great question, but a real problem faced by a gamer.

In these cases retag minus the Steam tag? Or leave them alone? These are just some of the recent ones. I find Steam tag attached to a lot of game questions that have nothing to do with the game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the first one might, but not the rest. (since the crates/keys are steam inventory items and I think are open-able outside of the game)

the questions are using the steam tag the same way people incorrectly use xbox or playstation tags. The policy (as outlined [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50/should-questions-always-be-tagged-with-either-a-console-platform-or-with-multi)) is to only include a platform specific tag when the problem does not exist for the game on other platforms.

proposed retagging:

link 1: [counter-strike-go](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-strike-go)

link 2: [super-steet-fighter-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-steet-fighter-4)

link 3: [tf2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tf2) [pc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pc)

link 4: [gunz-the-second-duel](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gunz-the-second-duel)

Comment: I don't think h264 is a particularly good tag, and perhaps should be erased from existence.

Comment: @shanodin Probably. I think that is the only question that uses it too.

Comment: +1, though I agree with shanodin that [h264] should be removed.

Comment: Yeah, [h264] is pretty much useless for us (I can see it possibly being useful on another SE), and as such, I've removed it.

Comment: @Vaishali These examples all use it the same way people use other platform tags (xbox, playstation, pc). Currently the policy is to remove them unless the problem is specific to that platform/version.