# Should questions about achievements/trophies for a specific game include the console-specific tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

For example, I had edited [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/253975/what-are-the-actual-requirements-for-playing-the-objective) and removed both the [ps4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ps4) and [xbox-one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-one) tags, since the question is concerned mainly about a specific trophy and/or achievement being bugged/patched/etc. I felt fairly confident that questions such as this do not follow the usage of the tags as described in the tag info:

PS4

> This tag should only be used if the question is about the Playstation 4 operating system or hardware, or a game feature truly unique to the PS4.

Xbox One

> This tag should only be used if the question is about the Xbox One operating system or hardware, or a game feature truly unique to the Xbox One.

Sure, you certainly could argue that these achievements (xbox, not steam) and trophies are specific to Microsoft and Sony console (respectively), but I believe questions like these have more to do with the game itself (hence the bug/patch aspect). Not to mention that trophies and achievements are not specific to PS4 and Xbox One (i.e. current gen consoles).

**Was I right in removing those tags/should they be re-removed?** Or are these tags legitimately used when dealing with trophies/achievements?

I'm not trying to argue one way or the other, just trying to clear up my understanding of how console tags are use and when/if they should *actually* be included.

Comment: Steam also has achievements, not just the various xboxen.

Comment: @GodEmperorDune - Very true.

Comment: There is also an achievements tag, so that would also be useful in these situations. (I would imagine that is why it was created...)

Comment: I already rolled back to your edit in the question before seeing this post, because the game in question (SW Battlefront) has the same achievements on Origin which is mandatory to play the game on PC. I also think that even if the achievements were console only, the tags wouldn't have been necessary although it could be argued that they wouldn't be "wrong" either, since the achievements would be a "unique game feature". I feel like the console tags are there to distinguish a really platform specific question, like the tag descriptions explain, and achievements are a pretty general thing imho.

Comment: Thanks @Kodama. I just wanted to post here for reference first, just in case some sort of rollback war started.

Comment: I added the achievement tag, as I usually do when the question is specific to achievements (or trophies).

Comment: I just wanted to note in regards to the bug for an achievement that I have seen instances where an achievement/trophy was bugged only on one console so there could be times where the console tag is not only applicable, but necessary, for the question to be answered correctly.

Comment: @Ryan - I would agree *if* it is actually limited to a specific console and not say, PS3 and PS4 just because they both have trophies. (i.e. If it happens on PS3: tag = ok. If it happens on both consoles: tag != ok). But that's just my opinion where it becomes a grey area if more than one platform has bug X, but not all platforms have bug X.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that we should apply the same principles as Oak's answer to this question:

[Should questions always be tagged with either a console/platform or with "multi-platform"?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50/should-questions-always-be-tagged-with-either-a-console-platform-or-with-multi)

> I think it should only be added when:
>
> 1. It's a general question about the platform, OR
> 2. The game in question has multiple versions, AND the question is specific to one of them (e.g. why can't I find gold nuggets in game X on the PS3, my friend is finding them in his PC version!)
>
> Otherwise the only added value I see in adding it is for filtering purposes - and while that is admittedly useful, I think it will encumber the tagging system a bit too much.

In addition, we have an [achievements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/achievements) tag that should be used for anything achievement related (which includes Playstation trophies).

Therefore, just having the game-specific tag and the [achievements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/achievements) tag should be sufficient for any question regarding the achievements in a game.  If the achievement in question is unique to one platform, then there is an argument for adding a platform-specific tag.  However, you usually find games have the same achievements across all platforms (not always, but it is often the case).

Comment: I think I agree with this, if you're saying that the tags should have been removed from that question due to the fact that the achievements were not actually console-specific, but that the tags would have been okay (but not exactly necessary) if the achievements were.

Comment: You can also take into consideration that some games may even have separate tags for each of their versions, for example Minecraft ([minecraft], [minecraft-console], [minecraft-windows-10] etc.)